# show and hide different div every two minutes

Tags: jquery, html, loops, delay, show-hide

I need two divs to switch places every two minutes (So one shows, and one hides). I'm pretty sure this needs to be done with Jquery but I'm still sort of a noob. I tried some examples I found online but none of them really seemed to work for me.

This is my html:

```
<div class="contentpanel">
    <div id="sect1"></div>
    <div id="sect2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me out, because I'm sort of stuck and overwhelmed by all the things I've read.

Comment: do you have any current jquery code if so then post it

Comment: look at `setInterval`, and `(ele).is(":visible")`

Comment: a) Doesn't need to be done with jQuery, but it'll be easier b) post what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: What about using a slider (there are MANY).  Are the div's on different places on the page.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with `setInterval`:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb7p6/)

```
setInterval(function(){
    if ($("#sect1").is(":visible")){
        $("#sect1").hide().siblings().show();
    }else{
        $("#sect2").hide().siblings().show();
    }
}, 1000); //1000 equals 1 sec
```

NOTE: while the other solutions are good in theory, `.toggle()` is deprecated as of version 1.8 and will not work in the latest versions

Comment: You are talking about the toggle event handler, which is different. See my answer.

Comment: This works very well! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

just use `toogle()` with `setInterval()` , make sure you have one div with `display:none` initially

like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".contentpanel div").toggle();
},2000); //1000 equals 1 sec
```

here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yq7N/)**

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `toggle` function associated with a `setInterval` like so :

```
setInterval(function(){$('#sect1, #sect2').toggle();},120000);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqrcj/)

**Edit**

The toggle event handler is deprecated as of jQuery 1.9.

[Toggle event Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

However the toggle method is **still in use**! It will work with jQuery 2.x

[Toggle method Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: blex and @amit: `toggle` is deprecated

Comment: @jmore009 doesn't seem to be. [**See jQuery Doc**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)